# Proof of Riesz Representation Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, riesz-representation-theorem

I was trying to understand the proof of RRT from my lecture notes, but I have trouble in understanding the following step.

$$T : L^{q} \rightarrow (L^{p})'$$

For $1 \leq p < \infty$. I understand the proof for showing that $T$ is linear, bounded and is an isometric mapping between the two spaces. I have trouble understanding the part in which $R(T)=(L^{p})'$. The proof proceeds by showing that $R(T)$ is dense in $(L^{p})'$.

We use the following result:

Let X be a n.s. Let $G \subset X$ be a subspace such that $ \overline{G} \neq X$. Then $\exists f \in X', f \neq 0$ such that
$$f(x)=0 \forall x \in G$$.

By contradiction, assume that $R(T)$ is not dense in $(L^{p})'$. Then by the result above, we get that $\exists f \in (L^{p})'', f \neq 0$ such that $$f(x)=0 \forall x \in R(T)$$

$$ f(Tu)=0, \forall u \in L^{q}$$

Then, we use the fact that $L^{p}$ is reflexive, thus there exists a canonical mapping from $L^{p}$ to $(L^{p})''$ given by
$$C_{x}(f)=f(x)\hspace{2mm} f \in (L^{p})'$$

From this, the conclusion is that there exists $f \in L^{p}$ such that $Tu(f)=0 \forall u \in L^{q}$. I cannot understand this last conclusion. Can someone clarify?

Comment: The reflexivity of $L^p$ means that your canonical mapping $C:L^p\to(L^p)''$ is onto. Hence your $f\in(L^p)'',f\ne0$ s.t. $\forall u\in L^q, f(Tu)=0$ is of the form $f=C_g$ for some $g\in L^p.$ Therefore, $Tu(g)=C_g(Tu)=f(Tu)=0.$